# Spring form not submitting

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc

I am using Spring SimpleFormController for my forms and for some reason it won't go to the onSubmit method

Here's my code:

```
public class CreateProjectController extends SimpleFormController {

ProjectDao projectDao;

public CreateProjectController() {
    setCommandClass(Project.class);
    setCommandName("Project");
    setSessionForm(true);
}
@Override
protected Object formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request)
        throws Exception {
    String id = request.getParameter("id");
    Project project = projectDao.getProjectByOutsideId(id);
    System.out.println("@formbacking object method");
    System.out.println("the success view is "+getSuccessView());
    return project;
}
@Override
protected ModelAndView onSubmit(Object command) throws Exception {
    Project project = (Project) command;
    System.out.println("this is the project title: "+project.getTitle());
    System.out.println("the success view is "+getSuccessView());
    projectDao.insert(project);

    return new ModelAndView(getSuccessView());
}
```

I know because it prints "@formbacking object method" string but not the "the success view is..." string and the :"this is the pr..." string. I see "@formback.." string in the console but not the last two whenever I hit submit.  I don't know where the problem is.

This is my jsp

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="Project">
Name: <form:input path="title"/><br/>
Description: <form:input path="description"/><br/>
Link: <form:input path="url" disabled="true"/><br/>
Tags: <form:input path="tags"/><br/>
Assessors <form:input path="assessors"/><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form:form>
```

I am running on Google App Engine btw. Maybe the problem is there?

UPDATE: The problem seems to be with the formBackingObject method. When I removed it, the form now goes to the onSubmit when I click submit.

But I'd like to have values from of the command class from the database in my forms.

Another piece of code that doesn't work:

```
    @Override
protected Object formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request)
        throws Exception {
    String id = request.getParameter("id");
    Project projectFromConsumer = projectDao.getProjectByOutsideId(id);
    Project project = new Project();
    String title = projectFromConsumer.getTitle();
    project.setTitle(title);
    project.setUrl("projectUrl");
    return project;
}
```

but this does work:

```
    @Override
protected Object formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request)
        throws Exception {
    String id = request.getParameter("id");
    Project projectFromConsumer = projectDao.getProjectByOutsideId(id);
    Project project = new Project();
    String title = projectFromConsumer.getTitle();
    project.setTitle("projectTitle");
    project.setUrl("projectUrl");
    return project;
}
```

Now I am really confused. haha.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking along the same lines as axtavt.  You are only going to have an id request parameter on updates, so you should add some code for creation forms:

FYI, formBackingObject requires a non-null object to be returned.  To save some memory, you can have a final constant member variable that is the default return value.  Your code satisfies this though since you're transferring objects, but I don't get why you're transferring data (creating an extra object) when you're not using a DTO.  You could simply do this:

```
private final static Project PROJECT_INSTANCE = new Project();
static {
    PROJECT_INSTANCE.setTitle("defaultProjectTitle");
}

@Override
protected Project formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    String id = request.getParameter("id");
    if(id == null || id.trim().length() == 0 || !id.matches("\\d+")) {
       return PROJECT_INSTANCE;
    }
    return projectDao.getProjectByOutsideId(id);
}
```

You don't need a hidden id input field.  You would use `formBackingObject()` for initializing the form input fields for updating (by navigating to page.jsp?id=111).

Comment: Hahaha. since all of you here are trying to tell me same thing, I think I'll give your suggestion a try. Cheers! :D

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `String id = request.getParameter("id");`. There is no such field in your form, so probably you get an error there during submit process, maybe, `getProjectByOutsideId` returns `null`.

P.S. It's strange that your `formBackingObject` is executing when you press submit, it shouldn't if you really set `setSessionForm(true)`.

Comment: getProjectByOutsideId is working, the jsp shows the values of the command class returned by getProjectByOutsideId.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning the spring debugging up.  It provides a lot of information, which can be helpful.  Do this by editing the log4j.properties file.

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework=DEBUG
```

Have you added logging to make sure the formBackingObject is returning something?

```
System.out.println("@formbacking object method is returning: " + project);
```

It will make sure something is being returned.  In general the formBackingObject should always return something.

EDIT:

Id is not being passed during submission in the snippet.  Maybe it is during the load, e.g. /page.do?id=4, but it doesn't appear in the form.

Add `<form:hidden path="id"/>` to your form during on submit.  Otherwise the id will not be a parameter and the getProjectByOutsideId will fail.

Comment: I know the formBackingObject is returning something because its populating the form in the jsp with values. The problem is that when I hit the submit button, it doesn't submit. And this should work whether you use the populated values or the ones you input.

Comment: Why do I need to put a hidden field with the form? If I am not mistaken the formBackingObject method is called when the client requests for the form view and not after the client hits submit. When I call this form I of course include the id with it. For example http://localhost:8888/createproject?id=[some id here]. After that the form shows. The problem is it won't submit/go to the success view when I click submit.

Comment: I think the id field is not being passed onsubmit.   Without the hidden field, you are calling localhost:8888/createproject, not localhost:8888/createproject... maybe add     System.out.println("id: " + id) below String id= request.getParameter("id");

to be sure.